# Geting Exception Bad Message when rename file on SFTP server using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am trying to move file from one to another directory on SFTP using JSch . I have used rename method but getting below exception(5: Bad message):

```
    channelDes = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channelDes.connect();
    sftpChannelDes = (ChannelSftp) channelDes;

    String sourcePath = "./abc/" + fileName;
    String destinationPath = "./xyz/" + fileName;

    sftpChannelDes.rename(sourcePath, destinationPath);


    **Exception :-**
    =================

         5: Bad message

         at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)

         at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1923)

         at com.test.CopyFile.moveFile(CopyFile.java:56)

         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: Did you try using absolute paths? Did you first try moving the file using a standalone (command-line or GUI) client?

Comment: Looking [here](https://libraries.io/github/voyiger/projectV), it seems (though isn't very clear) that they were receiving a `bad message` exception when using relative `.` and `..` paths, so I would support @MartinPrikryl 's theory that using absolute paths may fix this for you.

Comment: Any update over this will be appreciated